# How configure jshint in a meanjs project with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, jshint, meanjs

I followed exactly [that tutorial](https://vexxhost.com/blog/mean-socket-io-integration-tutorial/) (I obviously replaced the vexxhost domain name by localhost:3000 for my tests).

And while calling grunt there is an error ('io' is not defined) but the server start without any other complain.

If I correctly understood the problem, jshint scan the whole project to validate the code and he finds on reference to an undefined variable ! But 'io' is defined when the whole application starts (because the script are loaded). In fact, that error is more a warning than an error

If I am right (and I hope some people here will correct me if I am not), that bring us to my question : How refactor the code or configure jshint to avoid that warning ?

If possible I would prefer to have an explicit reference to 'io'.

By advance thank you to everyone.

**EDIT**

My results from that tutorial are available [here](https://github.com/asirko/socket_meanjs) on github. The problematic file is `public/modules/core/services/socket.js`.

Comment: you would need to give us the code that is throwing the error (or warning). Don't forget to specify which line the error or warning is occurring on.

Comment: My guess would be it's complaining about `public/modules/core/services/socket.js`, and if it is, all you need to do is add a comment that specifies `io` as a global variable. Though, it should also be complaining about angular in that case, unless you've already specified it as a global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 way to configure JSHint to correct that error :

- if you are calling the `io` variable in several place of the code. JSHint is configurable in the `.jshintrc` file, there is a a global section where it is possible to add `"io": true`. With that modification, JSHint should consider io as a global variable.
- Or if you only call the `io` variable once, you can add the comment `/* global io: true */` directly in the file where you  are calling it.